# How do I update my full list of games on my Offline PC?

Tags: steam

So when I got Steam working offline I had 26 games listed in my library but only 2 installed. Recently I brought a bunch more so I want to update my library on my Offline PC with the full list that's on my Online Laptop.

I thought that all I would need just copy the data from `userdata/[ID]/config/localconfig.vdf` however when I do the number goes down to 2 (the number of games I do have installed) and also the OST I got with *Monster Monpiece* doesn't appear. When I restore just that file the list and the music listing returns.

So what do I need to copy over from my Online Laptop to the Offline PC to update the list of games in the library?

Comment: Your `localconfig` file is only storing settings that Steam requires to work offline, mostly security tokens and server URLs. You can look in your AppData's Steam folder and see if any of the files there contain what you need. You could also just copy over the entire steam install folder from your laptop.

Comment: From a DRM standpoint it sound very unlikely you'll be able to copy a file just to add games to an offline PC. Can't you connect it for a moment? You'll have to do that sooner or later anyway.

Comment: @SumanRoy i want to avoid copying the entire Steam Folder incase if they ever update it which stops the Offline Mode i got working. as for the appdata/steam folder all i see that might be relevant is a cache folder. i'll try copying that

Comment: @Mario not with the PC. it's 7 years old and without an Anti-Virus. don't want to risk my gaming PC by putting on the net without one for any period of time.

Comment: You can't catch malware behind a properly configured router, if you only open Steam to let it update. Don't open anything else and you're fine.

Comment: @Mario still kinda worried but even if i was guaranteed 100% safety there is also the problem that my PC can only be connected to the net via a cable. the router is at the other end of the house so for me to connect i have to unplug my entire PC and move it though the house. doing this as a means to update Steam is hardly ideal. also there is the backlog of Windows Updates which i don't want because when i upgraded to Win 7 SP1 it undid some patched Windows libraries which allowed me greater customization of the start menu and windows (eg the window [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39PTe.png))

Comment: I have to ask though, why do you want your offline PC to list games that haven't been downloaded? Because if you just want to use that system to play your downloaded games, just copy your `steamapps` folder from your laptop.

Comment: @SumanRoy a kind of OCD. it just doesn't feel right knowing the list on my offline PC ain't up to date when i buy a bunch of stuff

Comment: Haha, I get it. I'm not completely sure which file/s is/are used by Steam to maintain that list while offline and digging through them would take too much time. One possible way to find the file(s), if you're on a Win10 laptop, would be use the Powershell to `grep` the steam install folder with  the name of a game that you haven't downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

The Offline PC setup for Steam is something I have done for several years now, and it has been wonderful (part of my motivation is playing games without Steam remembering my every move).

As mentioned in the comments, any DRM game MUST be launched at least once from the Online Laptop. At first, this might seem like a deal-breaker, but this turns out to be OK.

Also, you have said that you want to avoid copying the entire Steam folder. This turns out to be OK, too, even when there are updates to Steam.

*Everything below can be done by simply moving around files/directories, and having some basic knowledge of the Windows Registry. While there are some powerful things you can do with Steam config files, I have avoided any kind of customization since it can change so much between updates.*

---

Step by step:

- Login to the Steam client, with the "Remember my password" box checked
- Make sure any DRM game has been launched at least once from the internet PC
- Copy the entire Steam directory to portable media and over to the Offline PC

Now, from the Online Laptop, open the Windows Registry, and export the following key to a file:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Valve\Steam
```

The resulting file should look like this (if there is more, just delete it and keep the parts about "AutoLoginUser" and "RememberPassword"):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Valve]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Valve\Steam]
"SuppressAutoRun"=dword:00000000
"Restart"=dword:00000000
"Language"="english"
"BigPictureInForeground"=dword:00000000
"AutoLoginUser"="[YOUR STEAM USER NAME - ALL LOWERCASE]"
"RememberPassword"=dword:00000001
"TempAppCmdLine"=""
"TempAppPath"=""
"AlreadyRetriedOfflineMode"=dword:00000000
"WebHelperFirewall"=dword:00000001
```

Copy the exported `.reg` file to the Offline PC and import it.

---

I have been doing this for several years -- and many Steam updates -- and it has been great. There may be times when a Steam update is copied to the Offline PC for the first time and you will be presented with a login screen(!). Just import the `.reg` file on the Offline PC again, and it will go back to using your `AutoLoginUser` and allow you to select Offline mode.

Also, I presume that you were trying to avoid updates to **Steam** and not updates to **individual games**. I have found the updates to Steam to be harmless. And while I have no first-hand experience with avoiding updates to individual games, they are files/directories like everything else. If you already have an old edition of a game on the Offline PC, you ought to be able to copy the entire Steam folder *except the files for that game* (located in `SteamApps\common`).

If you want to test all this out just to prove to yourself that Offline mode will continue working, that is a good idea. Use an extra PC if you have one. Otherwise, two Steam installations can be run on one PC, since Steam does not actually need to be installed before using it -- you can simply run the Steam executable from portable media (although you may want to backup the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Valve\Steam` and maybe the files in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Steam`, just in case you have an issue later and need to restore your original settings.)

Comment: Added bonus: if you earn achievements on the Offline PC, you can (manually) get them to show up on your Steam account! Find the ID of the game you're playing (for instance, lookup [Portal 2](http://store.steampowered.com/app/620/) in the Steam Store, and notice it has ID 620 in the URL) Navigate to `appcache\stats` and find a file named `UserGameStats_[PLAYER ID]_[GAME ID].bin`. Copy it to portable media, copy it to the same place on the Online laptop, launch Steam, and you're done.