# How to Restore Steam Games

Tags: steam, windows, windows-10

Help! I backed up my "common" folder when I reset my PC, but now, when I try to copy it into "steamapps", Steam doesn't detect the files AT ALL. I have really slow internet, so I'd be looking at about a week of re-downloading my 14 games if I can't resolve this!

I'm on windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not be able to restore just the `common` directory that contain the application binaries.

There are appmanifest files in the `SteamApps` directory itself, cache files scattered all over the place, and other pieces that provide context for the actual application binaries.

Steam can be run from a removable drive in so-called "portable mode". But you must backup the entire Steam directory.

---

For more information, see this question: [How do I update my full list of games on my Offline PC?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/304851/53249)